# SQL error in MySQL query: Error: Unknown column 'post_taxonomy_category' in 'on clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

SQL error in MySQL query:

> Error: Unknown column 'post_taxonomy_category' in 'on clause:

```
SELECT post_taxonomy_category_tbl.NAME         AS post_taxonomy_category, 
       post_meta_date_published_tbl.meta_value AS post_meta_date_published, 
       post_meta_author_tbl.meta_value         AS post_meta_author, 
       posts_post.post_title                   AS post_post_title, 
       posts_post.post_content                 AS post_post_content 
FROM   wp2k_posts AS posts_post 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT NAME, 
                          object_id AS id 
                   FROM   wp2k_terms AS post_taxonomy_category_tbl_terms 
                          INNER JOIN wp2k_term_taxonomy AS 
                                     post_taxonomy_category_tbl_termtaxonomy 
                                  ON 
post_taxonomy_category_tbl_termtaxonomy.term_id = 
       post_taxonomy_category_tbl_terms.term_id 
       AND post_taxonomy_category_tbl_termtaxonomy.taxonomy = 
       'category' 
       INNER JOIN wp2k_term_relationships AS rel_post_taxonomy_category_tbl 
       ON post_taxonomy_category_tbl_termtaxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = 
       rel_post_taxonomy_category_tbl.term_taxonomy_id) AS 
                  post_taxonomy_category_tbl 
               ON post_taxonomy_category_tbl.id = posts_post.id 
                  AND post_taxonomy_category = 'Published & Accepted Papers' 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT post_meta_date_published_tbl_posts.id AS id, 
                          meta_value, 
                          meta_key 
                   FROM   wp2k_postmeta AS post_meta_date_published_tbl_postmeta 
                          INNER JOIN wp2k_posts AS 
                                     post_meta_date_published_tbl_posts 
                                  ON 
post_meta_date_published_tbl_postmeta.post_id = 
           post_meta_date_published_tbl_posts.id 
AND post_meta_date_published_tbl_posts.post_type = 
    'post') AS post_meta_date_published_tbl 
               ON post_meta_date_published_tbl.meta_key = 'date_published' 
                  AND post_meta_date_published_tbl.id = posts_post.id 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT post_meta_author_tbl_posts.id AS id, 
                          meta_value, 
                          meta_key 
                   FROM   wp2k_postmeta AS post_meta_author_tbl_postmeta 
                          INNER JOIN wp2k_posts AS post_meta_author_tbl_posts 
                                  ON post_meta_author_tbl_postmeta.post_id = 
                                     post_meta_author_tbl_posts.id 
                                     AND post_meta_author_tbl_posts.post_type = 
                                         'post') 
       AS post_meta_author_tbl 
               ON post_meta_author_tbl.meta_key = 'author' 
                  AND post_meta_author_tbl.id = posts_post.id 
WHERE  1 = 1 
       AND posts_post.post_type = 'post'
```

Comment: Remember that column aliases can't be used in the ON clause. Does your table have a column post_taxonomy_category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use column aliases in the `on` clause. You'll have to use the real name instead - `post_taxonomy_category_tbl.name`.

Comment: ON post_taxonomy_category_tbl.ID = posts_post.id 
     AND post_taxonomy_category_tbl.name = 'Published &amp; Accepted Papers'